# How to configure server settings in AWS hosted Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I am using Amazon Elasticsearch Service, with its built-in Kibana.  I need to set up a reverse proxy to this Kibana instance, so I need to set the server.basePath setting.

Normally, with self-hosted Kibana, you would set it in the kibana.yml file. However, I don't know how to access this when it's being hosted by AWS.

Is there a way to edit the kibana.yml file, or some sort of dashboard that lets me edit the values that would be contained in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Amazon Elasticsearch Service is a fully managed service, users are not allowed access to kibana.yml or even elasticsearch.yml ​file. Users are allowed to edit various settings via console or cli, but unfortunately "server.basePath" is not one of them.

AWS Documentation for no access to yml files:

> You can't use SSH to access any of the nodes in your Elasticsearch
> cluster, and you can't directly modify elasticsearch.yml

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html